# How to run a haskell application in emacs - haskell mode?

Tags: haskell, emacs, haskell-platform, haskell-mode

Code in helloworld.hs :

> main = do
>     putStrLn "Hello, what's your name?"
>     name <- getLine
>     putStrLn ("Hey " ++ name ++ ", you rock!")

Application tested in Terminal:

> optimight@optimight:~$ ghc --make helloworld
>   [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( helloworld.hs, helloworld.o )
>   Linking helloworld ...
>   optimight@optimight:~$ ./helloworld
>   Hello, what's your name?
>   John
>   Hey John, you rock!

helloworld.hs loaded in emacs - haskell major mode:

> GHCi, version 7.4.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
>   Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
>   Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
>   Loading package base ... linking ... done.
>   Prelude> :load "/home/optimight/helloworld.hs"
>   [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /home/optimight/helloworld.hs, interpreted )
>   Ok, modules loaded: Main.
>   *Main>

Now, **How to (What is the procedure? ) test it in emacs - haskell mode environment?** (I believe, while I am using emacs - haskell mode , there should be no need to switch over to terminal.)

Comment: Your question is how to use REPL (read eval print loop) for Haskell under emacs.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: Okay, so how to use REPL for Haskell under emacs?

Comment: Simply type `main` at the ghci prompt inside Emacs, or whatever function you would like to test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do something similar to what you did on the command line you need to load your program in ghci (which you have done) and then call the `main` method (which you can do by just typing `main` at the prompt).

Comment: Is there a way send "main" in GHCI with a key stroke? (without loosing the focus from edit window)

Comment: ...found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213717/function-to-evaluate-haskell-in-ghci-while-editing-source-file-using-emacs