# Function to evaluate haskell in ghci while editing source file using Emacs

Tags: haskell, emacs, ghci

I'm editing a haskell source file. I want to run my main function in my inferior-haskell buffer (already opened in a different frame) and continue editing my source file. To do this, I do

`C-c C-l`, change frame, `main<ret>`, change back to original frame

This seems quite inefficient. I'd like an emacs function/key that does it one shot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is actually a function to do this already defined in `inf-haskell.el`: `inferior-haskell-load-and-run`. This loads your current file and runs `:main`.

You can bind it to a key in Haskell mode by adding a hook:

```lisp
(defun my-haskell-mode-hook ()
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-x C-r") 'inferior-haskell-load-and-run))
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'my-haskell-mode-hook)
```

However, playing around with this for a bit, it seems to have an odd issue on my computer: sometimes, when it pops to the `*haskell*` buffer, it doesn't move the point to the end. I find this rather annoying. You can easily fix it by moving the point to the end yourself:

```lisp
(defun my-haskell-load-and-run ()
  "Loads and runs the current Haskell file."
  (interactive)
  (inferior-haskell-load-and-run inferior-haskell-run-command)
  (sleep-for 0 100)
  (end-of-buffer))
```

I believe the `sleep-for` is necessary because the Haskell command is run asynchronously and takes a little bit of time to return. This whole thing is something of a hack, but it seems to work.

Also, you might want to customize exactly what the `inferior-haskell-run-command` is. By default, it's `:main`. However, for me, I think just `main` would be better because `main` is affected by `:set args ...` where `:main` isn't.

If you want to stay in your current Haskell buffer, you can just do this:

```lisp
(defun my-haskell-load-and-run ()
  "Loads and runs the current Haskell file."
  (interactive)
  (let ((start-buffer (current-buffer)))
    (inferior-haskell-load-and-run inferior-haskell-run-command)
    (sleep-for 0 100)
    (end-of-buffer)
    (pop-to-buffer start-buffer)))
```

Comment: This works great except my focus is on the inferior-haskell frame at the end. I'd like it to be on the source file I was editing.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to just pop back to the buffer you started at. I'll just edit that into my answer.

Comment: Thank You. To catch all exceptions in the Inf-Haskell log, in my case I increased wating time a bit. (sleep-for 1 750)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one little thing: there is an odd behaviour if you try to send a buffer with compilation error (I used the last code snippet). If there is a compilation error, the cursor jumps to the end of edit buffer.

Comment: @oshyshko: Oh, interesting. I'm not sure what could be causing that. Also, there's been a new inferior-haskell mode recently which might be causing bugs. Do you know if that's the one you're using?

Answer (score 1):

To use interactive-haskell-mode, I found a similar setting than the other answer:

```
(defun my-haskell-load-and-run ()
  "Loads and runs the current Haskell file main function."
  (interactive)
  (haskell-process-load-file)
  (haskell-interactive-mode-run-expr "main"))
(defun my-haskell-mode-hook ()
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-x C-r") 'my-haskell-load-and-run))
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'my-haskell-mode-hook)
```

But I have a small issue with it, it always jumps to the end of the source buffer... which can be annoying.